# minidom.Document v minidom.Document.documentElement?

Tags: python, xml

[Dive into Python: Scripts and Streams](http://diveintopython.net/scripts_and_streams/index.html) -

```
class KantGenerator:
    def _load(self, source):
        sock = toolbox.openAnything(source)
        xmldoc = minidom.parse(sock).documentElement
        sock.close()
        return xmldoc
```

I am curious, why do we have `documentElement` attribute when -

```
xmldoc = minidom.parse(sock)
```

would have given me the same thing as well? (seems both refer to the current instance)

A `pydoc` query is not giving me much clue either.

```
$ pydoc xml.dom.minidom.Document.documentElement
xml.dom.minidom.Document.documentElement
    Top-level element of this document.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `minidom.Document` is a [xml.dom.Document](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html#dom-document-objects) object, while `minidom.Document.documentElement` is an [xml.dom.Element](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html#dom-element-objects) object.

The `Document` contains extra things, like encoding, where the `Element` contains the actual XML data.

There can only be one `Element` in the main document (hence `documentElement`), where an element can have many children of other elements.

They both share many methods (both are derived from `xml.dom.Node`), so in many cases they can be interchangeable.

Comment: but `minidom.Document.firstChild` also returns me the single `Element` of `Document`. In that case the data attributes `documentElement` and `firstChild` seem to refer to the same instance.

Comment: That is true because `xml.dom.Node`, which both `Document` and `Element` extend from, contains the `firstChild` attribute. Since documents can only have one child element, it makes sense that `firstChild` and `documentElement` return the same thing. An `Element` node does not, by comparison, have a `documentElement` attribute.